# CSS How to prevent background showing through when scrollbar is active

Tags: css

Does anyone know how to remove the thin gap to the left of the scrollbar that is letting the background through (showing green on this example)?

```
.menu {
   min-width: 195px;
   max-height: 200px;
   overflow: auto;
   position: fixed;
   background-color: #F9F9F9;
   border: solid 1pt yellow;
}

.button {
  border: solid 1px white;
  min-width: 200px;
}

body {
  background-color: green;
}


<div id="x" class="menu" style="top: 100px; left: 100px;">
   <div class="button">a</div>
   <div class="button">b</div>
   <div class="button">c</div>
   <div class="button">d</div>
   <div class="button">e</div>
   <div class="button">f</div>
   <div class="button">g</div>
   <div class="button">h</div>
   <div class="button">i</div>
   <div class="button">j</div>
   <div class="button">k</div>
   <div class="button">l</div>
   <div class="button">m</div>
   <div class="button">n</div>
   <div class="button">o</div>
   <div class="button">p</div>
```

A running example of this can be found on https://jsfiddle.net/Abeeee/f9jtsrw0/29/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like a bug to me but I replaced:

```css
border: solid 1pt yellow;
```

from your `.menu` with:

```css
border: solid 1px yellow;
```

The `pt` seems to make rounding errors occur.

Answer (score 1):

I've added `border-right: 0pt;` to the menu css which removes the right border.

```css
.menu {
  width: 200px;
  height: 195px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #F9F9F9;
  border: solid 1pt yellow;
  border-right: 0pt;
}
.button {
  border: solid 1px white;
  width: 200px;
}
 body {
  background-color: green;
}
.background {
  background-color: white;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div id="x" class="menu" style="top: 100px; left: 100px;">
  <div class="background">
  <div class="button">a</div>
  <div class="button">b</div>
  <div class="button">c</div>
  <div class="button">d</div>
  <div class="button">e</div>
  <div class="button">f</div>
  <div class="button">g</div>
  <div class="button">h</div>
  <div class="button">i</div>
  <div class="button">j</div>
  <div class="button">k</div>
  <div class="button">l</div>
  <div class="button">m</div>
  <div class="button">n</div>
  <div class="button">o</div>
  <div class="button">p</div>
  </div>
</div>
```